# I want validate unicode in dict python

Tags: python, validation, serialization

I tried try cat block, to validate dictionary within dictionary and list within dictionary has unicode or not.

```
def convert(input):
 if isinstance(input, dict):
     for key, value in input.iteritems():
        temp = {convert(key):convert(value)}
        return temp
 elif isinstance(input, list):
     for element in input:
         temp1 = [convert(element)]
        return temp1
 elif isinstance(input, unicode):
    return input.encode('utf-8')
 else:
    #return input
    print input
```

I want result from this function, if has unicode, element in dictionary or element encode with `utf8`. But I got error like this:

```
$python main.py
  File "main.py", line 21
    return temp1
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Indentation defines block structure in Python. When you unindent, the unindented line has to line up with a previous indentation level. Your `return` statement is indented tincorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indents are like curly brackets if you are familiar with them whenever you declare a block like `if else` `for` loops `class` definition or `function` definition it expect to find indentation level that is space or tab same indentation level treat it as one block If you want nested block you do like this:

```
 def myfunction(arg): #one block
     for x in range(0,arg): #indents at starting
         if x==1:#another block
            print('one')#more indents for nesting
```

so in your code

```
def convert(input):
 if isinstance(input, dict):
     for key, value in input.iteritems():
        temp = {convert(key):convert(value)}
        return temp
 elif isinstance(input, list):
     for element in input:
         temp1 = [convert(element)]
        return temp1 #here it expects to be in same indent level temp1 = [convert(element)] is at
 elif isinstance(input, unicode):
     return input.encode('utf-8')
 else:
     #return input
     print input
```

that is fixed in answer given by @Andronicus